# When i try to get the : nvcc --version I get this error:

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, cuda, gpu

I get this response:

```
$ nvcc
nvcc: command not found
```

this is in my bashrc file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-12.4/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-12.4/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

I did install Cuda 14.2

Ubuntu Server 22.04

Comment: Assuming you made a typo on Cuda 14.2, PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH modifications are made in .profile

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are concerned about a problem with your `$PATH` but it's worth checking the command is available somewhere on your system first.

First of all, check that `nvcc` is installed. From a search on Ubuntu packages, you can confirm it is included in the [nvidia-cuda-toolkit](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=nvcc&mode=exactfilename&suite=kinetic&arch=any) package.

To see what the status on your system is:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Should produce some output if the package has been installed from the Ubuntu software repos has been installed on your system. If not available, try: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

Now you can be fairly sure that the package is available on your system. The default location for nvcc when installed from the Ubuntu software repos is `/usr/bin/nvcc`. If this isn't in your path, you will have far bigger problems!! But you can check it's there:

```
ls -al /usr/bin/nvcc
```

If you think you may have installed nvcc from a non-official Ubuntu source and the binary might be somewhere on your system, try: `find / -name nvcc 2>/dev/null`

You can then [update your `$PATH`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-view-and-update-the-linux-path-environment-variable) with the additional location.